# email to case download link and routing addresses

Tags: email2case

I'm trying to understand how the Email-2-Case works. 
I thought I would start with installing the agent but the download link in the help docs sends me back to the same help page. Are there any alternative links?
I struggle with the concept of handling email behind the firewall and having routing addresses in Salesforce. I thought seeing config of the agent might help. What exactly is handled behind firewall and what gets forwarded to Salesforce? Also is it still true that E2C supports only IMAP?

Answer (score 2):

You've not given us a link to what agent you're referring to, so your question is difficult to answer. I'm going to guess that to get the [email to case agent](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Email_To_Case) to install behind your firewall you've gone to the wiki. Email-to-Case is **only** used if you have a requirement to keep all email traffic within your firewall and you want to accept email attachments larger than 10 MB from customers. The directions for setting it up are found in the following document: [Setting Up Email-to-Case or On-Demand Email-to-Case](https://help.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=01530000001x32vAAA).

If you don't need to handle everything behind your firewall or process attachments larger than 10 MB, you can set up On-Demand Email to Case as described in the same document without using the email to case agent. In that situation, an Apex email handler is used to process the email through Salesforce for you. More details are described in the referenced document that details the differences between the two.

**Edit**

I spoke with Salesforce Support yesterday and learned why they're no longer supporting the Email-to-Case client and what the recommended solution is.

The Email-to-Case client requires you to store a user's log-in your credentials in a config file or Java Jar class. That makes the E2C client less secure, thus the reason Salesforce has removed the download link for it and is no longer supporting new instances of it (very limited support for existing installs).

Support recommends that you use the On Demand Email2Case which is more more secure as there's no need to store any credentials. All you need do is set up emails to from your case support email address to forward to the email address that you'll configure in OnDemand Setup.

Once you do that, it will work from behind your firewall and recognize that it's been forwarded from your server to and is a new case from the contact who originated the email. You can even configure the service to only accept emails from your support email address if you want to; making it more secure in terms of in-bound emails. The down side to this solution is that you'll still need to deal with the replies you send coming from a Salesforce Server using the email address that you'll configure in the OnDemand Setup. It won't originate from your server.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know the difference but perhaps I understand the firewall wrongly. As per the docs you posted one needs an email routing address in SFDC for the Email-To-Case. Now how does it work?  My naive understanding was that emails are send to company x, forwarded to the agent using config in the mail server, agent would create cases using SOAP api. But it looks like it's other way round. Salesforce has email service one forwards email to from behind the firewall?

Comment: It's been 25MB for a while btw.  Has anyone ever seen the instruction how to configure the agent itself? I looked all over and all I can find is is the official 2 pages help on how to enable &  configure email to case

Comment: My understanding of the docs (I've not setup Email2Case) is that one forwards emails from behind their firewall to Salesforce using a routing IP address that gets configured for each type of case which causes the case to be auto-created. I see that @cropredy has posted that E2C is no longer supported which is contrary to the help docs. I'll ping #asksalesforce on Twitter to ask what's going on.

Comment: @crmprogdev did you find out any more? we want to do this but have sever firewall restrictions. We might be able to configure a redirect to SF but the bit I don't understand is how SF will go back/forth with internal users who send an email thus creating a case. Will ALL case emails from SF originate for a single SF email address (the one created by SF when we confirm at the beginning)? If so we might be able to open firewall for that 1 email address I guess......I have to assume we're not the first SF customer to do this but can't seem to find a simple how to best practise for this anywhere

Comment: @keerz There didn't appear to be any further reason to do more follow up with Support.  Just configure Email2Case within the constraints of your firewall settings. Review the Docs on how it works. You're essentially routing all your cases through one address into your org. Your internal users can create cases in many different ways. If you have an email address that redirects to email to case, your cases will be created for you.

Answer (score 2):

Email2Case Agent is no longer supported by SFDC. How do I know? I tried to follow the doc links on Email2Case Agent and they directed me to On-Demand E2C pages (a call with SFDC Support confirmed this)

> My name is XXX YYYY and I have taken the ownership of your case #
>   15774060 regarding "Email 2 Case Agent help documentation redirects to
>   On Demand Email 2 Case".
>
> Email to case Agent is no longer supported by Salesforce support.
>   That's why you unable to find any related documentation on this.
>   However, You may check below KB article link which may help you:
>
> How do I get started with Email-to-Case?
>   https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-I-get-started-with-Email-to-Case&language=en_US
>
> Since this is out of scope for our support, your case will be closed.
>   Please let me know if you have further questions for us.

Comment: OMG! Can't believe it